# What are filler words that you can use for responding to users' saying in user interview?

Tags: user-research, interview, user-interviews

In user interviews, I often say "very interesting" or "that's an interesting point" or "very helpful" in response to users answer. "Interesting" is a perfect word choice because it has a neutral feeling, doesn't really mean good or bad. Sometimes it would be very repetitive for keep saying those in a long conversation. Would you suggest any other phrases or words to response to users?

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use...

"Curious, what else?" or 
"I'll note that, continue?" or 
"Do you see other items of interest?" or
"Great observation!"

Each of these is situational, and I use them to both acknowledge the comment and prompt to move forward.

Comment: oh thanks. this's helpful